# Методы для пустых указателей

Tags: golang, указатели, методы

Недавно наткнулся на такую особенность работы с указателями на типы в Golang.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type s struct {
    Data int
}

func (x *s) Size() {
    _ = x.Data
}

func (x *s) PrintSomething() {
    fmt.Println("something")
}

func main() {
    var obj *s
    obj.PrintSomething()
    obj.Size()
}
```

Почему у **пустого** указателя на тип вызов метода PrintSomething() **не приводит** к ошибке?

Где можно подробно почитать почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод в Go - это функция, которая объект (или указатель на него) принимает первым аргументом. [Spec: Method declarations.](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations)

```go
type X struct {
    X string
}

func (X) NoObject() {} // или func (_ X) NoObject() {}
func (x X) Object() { x.X += "Object" }

func (*X) NoPointer() {} // или func (_ *X) NoPointer() {}
func (x *X) Pointer() { x.X += "Pointer" }
```

Это то же самое, что и

```
func NoObject(X) {} // или func NoObject(_ X) {}
func Object(x X) { x.X += "Object" }

func NoPointer(*X) {} // или func NoPointer(_ *X) {}
func Pointer(x *X) { x.X += "Pointer" }
```

И нет никакой причины, по которой метод не мог бы принимать `nil` или условное ничего. Более того, такой подход позволяет создавать пустые типы со своими методами, например:

```
type Discard struct{}

func (Discard) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    return len(p), nil
}
```

Например [io/ioutil](https://golang.org/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go#L110). *Кстати в этом примере, `devNull` лучше бы сделать типа `struct{}`, a не `int`.*

Или так

```
type X struct {
    value int
}

func (x *X) Value() int {
    if x == nil {
        return 0
    }
    return x.value
}
```

[Анализ методов](https://play.golang.org/p/JLxVDyn05Kd) с помощью [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect).

Answer (score 0):

Потому что, как бы разработчики go не старались, а сишное прошлое постоянно вылазит наружу. В данном случае, на самом деле PrintSomething получает obj как первый параметр. Но так как он его не использует, то и проблем нет.

Должен ли компилятор ругнутся? не знаю. В данном случае скорее всего да, так как ошибка слишком очевидна. Должен ли ругаться при выполнении? только в дебаге.

Comment: Не вижу причин ругаться в любом случае. Функция может принимать указатель как параметр и ничего с ним не делать. Почему не может метод?

Comment: не совсем согласен. Все таки у нас тут объектоориентированный язык. И использование нулевого указателя, на котором вызывается метод - немножко как бы странная ситуация. А если методу все таки нужно будет обратиться к полям?

Comment: Касательно 2 предл.: многие объектные языки, начиная ЕМНИП со смолтока, позволяют определить методы на нуле. В руби `nil` имеет 68 (!) методов. Касательно 3: раз `len([]byte(nil))` не паникует, почему `(*MySlice)(nil).Len()` должен паниковать? Касательно 4: это очевидно ошибка программиста. (И ошибка создателей, что они вообще включили этот гадкий `nil` в язык.)